# How to setup a website with CMS on Amazon WS

Tags: content-management-system, amazon-web-services, web-hosting, modx, modx-revolution

Hi I was looking for a place to host my bigger projects with a philosophy "pay for what you use". I found Amazon WS. I want to set up a site with CMS (Modx) on Amazon WS. I basically need to setup a database (mysql?) and a webserver. Can someone provide me with some info on that or point to a tutorial or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, AWS gives you EC2 (CPU) and EBS (Hard Disk). You will need to choose an OS, setup Apache/Nginx and mysql.

In their basic form, the installation procedure is fairly simple.

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
sudo apt-get install mysql
```

Look around the web for more complete tutorials for the OS you choose. These are for ubuntu.

As for Modx, [their instructions are available.](http://rtfm.modx.com/display/MODx096/Installation)

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can also use a PaaS solution to assist you with the setup. Such as:

https://bitnami.com/stack/modx/cloud/amazon

This will enable you to build a CMS on any Cloud provider: AWS, Azure, etc. and add a layer of support and management on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

I have came across a tutorial available here: http://blog.jelastic.com/2013/06/25/deploy-modx-cms/

The tutorial seems to be more than comprehensive.
Seems you just need to pick up the needed instances, upload the application and configure the database.